# Convert one generic type to another in Golang

Tags: go, generics

I have a generic service that accepts an interface to perform it's logic, with types needing to be converted to interface types first. Here's a simple example to demonstrate the way I'm doing it right now:

```golang
package main

type Getter interface {
    Get(key string) string
}

type Service struct{}

func (i *Service) GetFoo(v Getter) string {
    return v.Get("foo")
}

type getterImpl map[string]string

func (m getterImpl) Get(key string) string {
    return m[key]
}

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{"foo": "bar"}
    i := Service{}
    s := i.GetFoo(getterImpl(m))
    println(s)
}
```

I'm now trying to make it generic, where the `Service` automatically converts the basic type to the interface type, but I'm not sure how to tell Go that the types are compatible.
See below for a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```golang
package main

type Getter interface {
    Get(key string) string
}

type Service[G Getter, T any] struct{}

func (i *Service[G, T]) GetFoo(v T) string {
    return G(v).Get("foo") // this is the offending line
}

type getterImpl map[string]string

func (m getterImpl) Get(key string) string {
    return m[key]
}

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{"foo": "bar"}
    i := Service[getterImpl, map[string]string]{}
    s := i.GetFoo(m)
    println(s)
}
```

This fails with the error `cannot convert v (variable of type T constrained by any) to type G`. It's obvious why it fails as `T` might not be convertible to `G`, so I'm wondering if I can somehow specify a type constraint that limits `T` to types that can be converted to `G`.

EDIT:

Right now the production code has a wrapper around `Service` for every single type which then converts the argument to a `Getter` for that type before calling the common code, resulting in an awful lot of boilerplate.

Here is some code to better demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve and why the answer below won't work ([playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/y0a2q6u7_Ns)):

```golang
package main

type Getter interface {
    Get(key string) string
}

type Service[G Getter] struct{}

func (i *Service[G]) GetFoo(v G) string {
    return v.Get("foo")
}

type someService struct{}

func (s *someService) Request(key string) string {
    // ...
    return "a"
}

type someOtherService struct{}

func (s *someOtherService) Fetch(key string) string {
    // ...
    return "b"
}

type someServiceGetter someService

func (s *someServiceGetter) Get(key string) string {
    return (*someService)(s).Request(key)
}

type someOtherServiceGetter someOtherService

func (s *someOtherServiceGetter) Get(key string) string {
    return (*someOtherService)(s).Fetch(key)
}

func main() {
    a := Service[*someServiceGetter]{}
    b := Service[*someOtherServiceGetter]{}

    x := a.GetFoo(&someService{})
    y := b.GetFoo(&someOtherService{})

    println(x, y)
}
```

Comment: `G` is constrained as an interface already, so why define another constraint `T`? If the type is convertible it would also have to be convertible to `G` in the first place.

Comment: You're not converting to an interface with `getterImpl(m)`, you're converting a `map[string]string` to `getterImpl`, which happens to implement your interface. You don't need generics here, and there is no need to cast a struct to an interface it implements because Go does this automatically. https://gobyexample.com/interfaces

Comment: "I'm now trying to make it generic" Why? How would the code benefit from throwing generics at it?

Comment: @Gavin the whole issue is that they don't implement the interface so I'm creating types to do so. Will update the question to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Volker the reason for making it generic is to massively reduce the code. Right now there's a whole host of functions doing the same thing i.e. converting various different 3rd party services into a common interface to then pass them to a common function.

Comment: The problem with the second part of the question is that the derived type does not implement the interface that is given as the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the second type:

```
type Service[G Getter] struct{}

func (i *Service[G]) GetFoo(v G) string {
    return v.Get("foo") // this is the offending line
}

...

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{"foo": "bar"}
    i := Service[getterImpl]{}
    s := i.GetFoo(m)
    println(s)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for pointers that would need converting like `(*myImpl)(myPointerVar)`

Comment: I've updated the question with another example and stuck the code on the playground: https://go.dev/play/p/y0a2q6u7_Ns